# Why won't this SQL CAST work?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a `nvarchar(50)` column in a SQL Server 2000 table defined as follows:

```
TaskID nvarchar(50) NULL
```

I need to populate this column with random SQL GUID's using the `NEWID()` function (I am unable to change the column type to `uniqueidentifier`).

I tried this:

```
UPDATE TaskData SET TaskID = CAST(NEWID() AS nvarchar)
```

but I got the following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting
>   expression to data type nvarchar.

I also tried:

```
UPDATE TaskData SET TaskID = CAST(NEWID() AS nvarchar(50))
```

but then got this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 6, Line 1 
>   String or binary data would be
>   truncated.

I don't understand why this doesn't work but this does:

```
DECLARE @TaskID nvarchar(50)
SET @TaskID = CAST(NEW() AS nvarchar(50))
```

I also tried `CONVERT(nvarchar, NEWID())` and `CONVERT(nvarchar(50), NEWID())` but got the same errors.

**Update:**

Ok, my eyesight is going, the column size on the table is `nvarchar(32)` not 50. Deepest apologies for the timewasting and thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Do you have and triggers on this table?  You may be getting error messages from the trigger. sp_helpTrigger 'TaskData'

Comment: @GMastros - no, the problem was PEBKAC/PICNIC more commonly known as a code 'ID 10T'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This test script works fine for me... I can only suggest that maybe your TaskId isn't an NVARCHAR(50) like you say? Try an sp_columns just to check...

```
CREATE Table #TaskData (TaskId NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #TaskData (TaskId) SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), NEWID())
UPDATE #TaskData SET TaskId = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), NEWID())
DROP TABLE #TaskData
```

Answer (score 18):

When you do not specify the size of your varchar/nvarchar during a cast or convert, it defaults to 30 characters.  You need 36 characters to convert a guid to a string.  That is why you get the error.

Either of these will work:

```
Select Cast(NewId() as nvarchar(36)), CONVERT(nvarchar(36), NEWID())
```

Comment: This seems to me to be the most accurate answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following cast:

```
CAST(NEWID() AS varchar(255))
```

Answer (score 0):

use varchar data type, nvarchar needs double size